# how to set TextBox value as textfile name

Tags: c#, file, textbox

How can i set a textFile name as textbox value? my save file codes are ; i Tried to add it but always give error

```
const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\"+textBox1.Text.ToString+ ".txt";
            using(StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath))
            for (int a=0;  a<listBox1.Items.Count; a++)
             {
                string line = String.Format("{0},{1}", listBox1.Items[a], listBox2.Items[a]);
                SaveFile.WriteLine(line);

             }
```

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: There is no reference to a textbox in your code?

Comment: What do you want to do? Name the File like a Value of a Textbox? or give the Textbox the Name of your File?

Comment: i tried to replace that deneme with textbox1.text but it's not accepting that

Comment: Please show the relevant code where you tried to replace it, with the error that you are getting

Comment: trying to Name the File like a Value of a Textbox

Comment: const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\"+textBox1.Text.ToString+ ".txt";  
in this code for textbox given error operator + cannot be applied...

Comment: It should be `textBox1.Text` only and if you want to use `ToString`, then you are missing the () eg. `textbox1.Text.ToString()`

Comment: then do not use const...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd code it like this:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\";
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + textBox.Text))
{
    sw.Write("Whatever you want");

    // At the end you should use the .Close() Method
    sw.Close();
}
```

you have a path and add to that the Filename of your Textbox. Don't forget to type in the Ending in the Texbox!

**Your Problem is** that you use `const` you can't do `"Text" + TextBox.Text` because TextBox.Text ist not constant. You could use `readonly`, but then you have to declare the variable as class variable!

Comment: this code works but the format of file is not txt trying it to make text know

Comment: you have to type into the textbox: "FileName.txt"

Comment: or you cange the second line to `using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + textBox.Text + ".txt"))`

Comment: But i recommend to use the "FileName.txt" because then you can choose by user which fileformat you are writing, otherwise it is hardcoded.

Comment: it's working thank you very much Jens Horstmann.I'm just new programmer and taking long time to write even simple programs ^^ thank you for your help guys

Comment: No Problem. I can remember when i was in your Situation ;) Keep trieng and asking!

Comment: Jens can u help me for other problem ? i couldn't ask question dunno why

Comment: But it would be great when you could figure out why you can'T ask another question. Because otherwise this question end in chaos. maybe you have to wait 90 minutes when you have asked to much questions..

Comment: this program will run with solidworks,the program i write must do some procces with formules and export the result as txt file. i already wrote them and after the procces done,the results(numbers which i need for solidworks) getting in the txt file until here everything okay,but the  numbers are saving with seperator " , " (comma) i  need the make them dot couse for the import them to solidworks must be dot.how can i do them dot not comma

Comment: i guess your number is a double or decimal. you can format the number with a CultureInfo. When you have e.g. a "German Culture Info" your double is saved with "," seperator. When you choose "English Culture Info"  the string is written with ".". Google for `Culture Info` for more information. otherwise you need to show some code..

Comment: I fixed that problem :)) here the codes i wroted for the name space used globalization and Threading and two line kods      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Answer (score 0):

```
 string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\" + TextBox1.Text + ".txt";
            using (StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath))
                for (int a = 0; a < listBox1.Items.Count; a++)
                {
                    string line = String.Format("{0},{1}", listBox1.Items[a], listBox2.Items[a]);
                    SaveFile.WriteLine(line);

                }
```

Comment: i tried it to but it's not working the error is textbox does not exist already tried:(

Comment: get rid of the const.  Jens Horstmann's answer should take care of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helper class to extract the directory of your path, which then allows you to append a new file name at the end.

This will be useful when the sPath is not constant inside your application.

Example:

```
const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\deneme.txt";
string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + textbox1.Text + ".txt";
```

This can also be extented to use the extention of the original path:

```
const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\deneme.txt";

string thePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                 textbox1.Text +
                 Path.GetExtension(sPath);
```